# Azure Activity Log alert or notification on a Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am an admin of a subscription along with some other people.
In Azure is it possible to create Alerts(using Activity Logs) on my Subscription to Notify me if someone adds/modifies or deletes any resource.

I know that i can add alerts on individual resources, but i want to add an alert at the subscription level.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can select a resource, resource group, or an entire subscription for activity log signal

We could create the alert with Azure portal and set Alert Target subscription.

For more information, please refer to [Create, view, and manage activity log alerts using Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/alert-activity-log).

[image]